# How do you link two files in make, that both include a different library?

Tags: c, testing, makefile, header

I want to test my code in `test.c` which includes `main.h` with all the function declarations from `main.c`. I want to compile my `test.c` file with criterion, which on its own works fine like this: `cc -c test.c -o testing -I include -L lib -l criterion.3.1.0` and I compile my `main.c` in the same way and it works fine: `cc main.c -o output -I include -L lib -l SDL2-2.0.0`. But when I want to include a function from `main.c` in `test.c` it gives me a linking error.
The project architecture is like this:

main.c

```
#include "main.h"

int function1(){
    [...]
}
```

test.c

```
#include "main.h"
#include <criterion/criterion.h>

Test(sample,test_function1){
    cr_assert(function1() == 1);
}
```

main.h

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

extern int function1();
```

How do I have to compile/link these files in order to have my test-file use get access to the functions from `main.c`?

Comment: What linking error do you get?

Comment: Looking at your build commands, you are just trying to build binaries out of each individual source file.  Instead, you should be building object files from your source files and then linking those object files together into a single binary.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is compiling and linking the binary in a single command for each source file in your project.  The linker, with how you are doing this, is not aware of your other sources.  Instead, you should first build the object files for each source file, and then you can link those together to form your binary.

Building object files:

```
cc -c main.c -I include -o main.o

cc -c test.c -I include -o test.o
```

Linking:

```
cc -o testing main.o test.o -Llib -lcriterion.3.1.0 -lSDL2-2.0.0
```

Comment: if I do that it executes `main.c` instead of just giving `test.c` access to a specific function from `main.c`. My `main.c` is a game which then starts to run if I compile it the way you showed

Comment: You do not execute individual source files.  You execute the compiled program, which can consist of many source files.  The entry point into your program is the `main` function.  There is only one main function in a given program.  The source code you've provided does not show any main function, but I would assume that you probably did write one in your `main.c`.  If you want to build a second binary, you'll need a main function for it, probably in your `test.c` source file.  If you want to share some functions, split them out into a separate source file and link them in to both projects.

Comment: Ok so I'll have to create a new file `shared.c` which holds the function definition but no main() and link that file to `test.c`. Do I need at least one main() or does it also compile without one?

Comment: If you are building a program that will run, you will need a main function.  Without `main`, there's nothing for it to do.